# From view to model (Slim PHP framework / Idiorm / Paris)

Tags: php, slim, idiorm

The issue:

I have a timesheet application. It has an SQlite database. I am trying to find a way to present a GUI so that if the user clicks a square(a ) i need to paas the data from the template to the model (paris) so i can save it in theb SQlite database.

There are three tables one for users one for the timesheet and one for the department.

It is a timesheet like application.

The setup:

Slim php 
Idiorm/Paris
SQlite3

Does anyone know a good way to make the user click a  so that the data is passed on to the model from the view?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why dont you get the data from model into your controller and then pass it from controlelr to view, This is how MVC works

Comment: The problem is different. I know how to pass the data from controller to view. But how do you pass data from the view to the controller  for storage in the database? and how do i get the data that is entered in a timesheet? Maybe a screenshot can clarify -> http://postimage.org/image/cfu5dtfmp/

Comment: you want to enter data into database once you create some thing new inside your view and display the newly entered data while remaining on the same page?

Comment: It does not matter of the page needs to reload. As long as i can pass the data from View->(controller->)model->database. But yes that is what i mean.

Comment: Do you kno JQuery and ajax? Once you are on the page and when your click on a button for adding some record in the database call ana jax function which call a php funtion take your data and insert it in the table and the returns, on return you can reload the page with new data... If you can code it its ok . if not let me know I will provide some code for start

Comment: I am not aware of the technique. Could you point me in the right direction? (I am familliar with JQuery an .load functions)

Comment: Ok let me answer your question, wait

Comment: I found jquery php -> http://jquery.hohli.com/ and json -> http://www.json.org/ . I am looking forward to a little explanation because i stared learning Php not to long ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this is your view

```
<html> 
   <head>
   $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#add").on("click", function(e) {
                var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
                var time = date();
                var department = $('#department').val();
                var data = {uid:user_id, time:time, dept:department};
                $.ajax({
                    url: "add_into_db.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(msg) {
                       if(msg=="true"){
                            alert("Your dats is inserted successfully");
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                        else{
                             alert("Your data insertion failed");
                              return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();      
            });
        });
   </head>

   <body>
     // Some html here
     // input field for user
     // input field for time
     // input field for department
     // whatever data you want os send on click, include it here
     <input id ='add' type= 'submit' value 'Add'/> //Your submit button to add data via AJAX
   </body>
```

Yout php function which will add data into database

```
function add_into_db(){
  $user id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $time = $_POST['time'];
  $dept = $_POST['department'];

  // connect to your db
  // run your insert query

  If (insertion is successfull) {
     $msg = 'true';
     echo $msg;
  }
  else{
     $msg = 'false';
    echo $msg
  }
}
```

Hope it ill help you

Comment: Thank you. I think i can make it work with this example and the jquery php library from http://jquery.hohli.com/ .

Comment: Sure you can do it... If you need more help I will be happy to help.. best of luck